# OS X/Objective-C equivalent of ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: objective-c, macos, httpserver

Does anyone know if there is an OS X/Objective-C equivalent of the ASP.NET Web API? It needs to be able to run as an daemon/startup process, and should be able to respond to restful HTTP requests.

I've looked at packages like [CocoaHttpServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer), [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer), and [Barista](https://github.com/stevestreza/Barista), but they all appear to be HTTP servers that you embed in OS X/iOS applications, and not something you'd run on the system level.

Answer (score 0):

There's no system API on OS X to run a web server.

You can either run "real" web servers like Apache or Nginx on your OS X machine, or you can use a Obj-C HTTP server implementation like GCDWebServer and write your own wrapper tool that you then install and run as a daemon using launchd.